# adding class / data breaks hover function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, addclass

I'm hoping someone can tell me why adding a class to a div breaks the hover function I've already applied to that div? I'm using maphighlight and have have it so that the current section of the map says highlighted, but as soon as this function runs, the tooltip stops working and for the life of me I can't figure out why. I've tried re-adding the mapTooltip class within the function but this doesn't seem to make any difference, nor does applying the tooltip via the counties variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var counties = $('area[id]').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('href');
}).get().join(", ");
var county;

$('.map').maphilight({fillColor: 'd20a36'});
$('#list').hide();

    $('.mapTooltip').hover(function(){
            var title = $(this).attr('aTitle');
            $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
            .text(title)
            .appendTo('body')
            .fadeIn('normal');

    }, function() {
            $('.tooltip').remove();
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
            var mousex = e.pageX + 10; //Get X coordinates
            var mousey = e.pageY - 50; //Get Y coordinates
            $('.tooltip')
            .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
    });

$(counties).click(function() {
    county = 'lists.html ' + $(this).attr('href');
    var currentcounty = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#list').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#list').load (county)
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).data('maphilight', { alwaysOn: true }).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
        $('.selected').data('maphilight', { alwaysOn: false } ).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
        $(counties).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    };
    });
});
```